# Alternate Week start dates

Tags: tableau-api

Using tableau, I am trying to analyze data on a weekly basis but with some modifications.

I want the first week of any given month to end on a Saturday with a minimum of one week.

Middle weeks are 7 days long (Sunday to Saturday).

The last week of a month Should be from Sunday to the last day of the month.

This question is very similar to the solution of this question but with minor differences: https://community.tableau.com/thread/230894

Here is an example for April

Week 1 has April 1 start date

Week 2 has April 12 start date

Week 3 has April 19 start date

Week 4 has April 26 start date

[image]

Comment: I saw that there is always an issue with weeks when we work with dates. Depends if it is ISO etc. according to the screenshot above you will need to prep the data first I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
IF DAY([Update Time])<[ISO Time]
THEN IF [ISO Time] <=6
    THEN DATEADD('day',7-[ISO Time],[Update Time])
    ELSE DATEADD('day', 7-[ISO Time],[Update Time])
END
ELSE IF [ISO Time]<=6
    THEN DATEADD('day',-[ISO Time],[Update Time])
    ELSE DATEADD('day',7-[ISO Time],[Update Time])
END
END
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer. Note, 3 of your 4 cases evaluate to the same expression, so you could simplify it if you wished